# OS and spd-say in python

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, text-to-speech

Here's my code:

```
import os
os.system("echo spd-say 'hello'")
```

so why does this not work? it only prints

```
spd-say hello
```

Comment: Don't edit answers into the question

Comment: OK, don't you see i removed the answer  since the guy below answered it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you **[echo](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/echoh.html)** every thing after the command  .

***I can not get [spd-say](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/spd-say.1.html) to work . Not even in bash .***
`os.system("echo 'hello' | spd-say -e")`

or

... to use some punctuation . The program [echo](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/echoh.html) has its own rules , it must be strictly followed as well as pythons. The generic way in python is ... 
 `var = """ "This is a test string". It's done. """`

`os.system("""echo "Hello, it's a test." | spd-say -e """)`

**Explaination** : echo command outputs to stdout (standard output). To capture that out put ; use a pipe, the symbol | , a vertical line , which is located above the enter key on your keyboard , hold shift key and press that key to get | .
That will direct the out put into spd-say command .
Echo goes to stdout and is picked up by the terminal , so it is being redirected through a pipe in to spd-say . The -t is the command for spd-say to treat the input as text , spd-say -t , commonly called a switch , so spd-say -t has being switched to take text as an input .

**[Flite](http://www.festvox.org/flite/doc/index.html)** is the default text to speech program (default output module) for spd-say . Can use it directly .

`os.system(r"""echo "Hello. It's flite "  | flite""")`

or

`os.system("""flite "Hello, it's flite." """)` . The space at the end , before the last three double quotes is important, or otherwise will not work .

Here are some other alternatives :

### [say](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/say.1.html)

**Bash command** :

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep-gui-runtime
say hello
```

or

`say "Hello it's say, saying "hello" "`

**Python command** :

`os.system('say Hello')`

or

`os.system("""say "Hello it's say, saying "hello" " """)`

### [festival](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/festival.1.html)

**Bash command**:

```
sudo apt-get install festival
echo "hello" | festival --tts
```

**Python command** :

```
import os
os.system('echo "hello" | festival --tts')
```

### [espeak](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/espeak.1.html)

**Bash command** :

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
espeak "hello"
```

**Python command** :

```
import os
os.system('echo "hello" | espeak')
```

Comment: You can use the `edit` link directly underneath your post to make changes to it.

Comment: thank you it works for raspberry too